# Revalidating dynamic select based on previous select

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got two select boxes and the second it created dynamically upon the selection of an option in the first list.

First select validates fine but once the second is created, I want to validate it too, but it won't until I hit submit again.  From what I've read, I know I need to use .valid() to revalidate the field but am having trouble figuring out how to implement that within the confines of the jquery.validate rules - or if that is where to do it at all.

I've tried making a rule based on a depends and any selection from the previous list - i.e.

```
    select2: {
      required:   true,
       depends: function(element) {
         return $('#select1 option:selected').val() != '';
         $('#select2').valid();
    }
```

which doesn't work but I'm not sure how to structure it to make it work.  So, I could use a swift kick in the right direction.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: One kick is that you'd never put `.valid()` inside of a rule, or inside of the `.validate()` method.  Another kick would be to improve your question to include more of the code including the rest of your `.validate()` code and the relevant HTML markup.

Comment: Okay - good to know about the .valid(). In trying to find an answer I missed that piece. I subsequently found your post from 2015 and used that information to add a rule on the fly using valid() so that will work for now.  Thanks.